# Count all Fields in Except

Tags: c#, .net

I'm facing with the following problem:

- I have two Lists which I would like to compare to find out if ListA contains all ListB's Items.
- I also want to count them, so that I get how much elements are missing (if any).

Is there a simple and easy way to achieve this?

```
public static bool ContainsAllItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
{
    return !b.Except(a).Any();
}
```

Expected

```
public static int ContainsAllItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
{
     //Count how much Elements are missing or if there are some missing
     return count(!b.Except(a).Any());
}
```

Comment: Note that, if you have duplicated values `except` will not gives you the expected result. for example : a {3,4,4}, b {2,2,3} : result : 2 and count is 1, but the expected result {2,2} and count is 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq [`Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netcore-3.1) method to get count of elements which are present in List `b` but missing in List `a`

> Returns the number of elements in a sequence.

```
var count = b.Except(a).Count();
```

Your code will look like,

```
//Get count of elements which are present in List b, but missing in List a
public static int ContainsAllItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
{
     return b.Except(a).Count();
}
```